# JAR, when runs, looks for resource files inside the JAR (itselfe) or outside?

Tags: java, jar

A java program uses different files, stored under the path "src/main/resources/files/files.drl".
If I export this program as a run-able JAR and run this JAR, will it look for these files to be inside the JAR or it will look to be outside in a folder src->main->resources->files ?

A sample code how these files are used the Java program is :

```
drlFileName = "./src/main/resources/files/files.drl";
FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = new FileInputStream(drlFileName);
kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(fis), ResourceType.DRL);
```

Comment: By using FileInputStream you ask for using the `./src/main/resources/files/files.drl` relative to the working directory. To load it from the classpath resources (from the JAR) do `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/files/files.drl")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you package your application doesn't determine where it will find its resources in most cases. It will look in whatever directory you tell it to look in. If you specify a jar file, by using the various jar file APIs (e.g. `java.util.jar.JarFile`), then that's where your program will find its data. If you look in your OS's file system (e.g. using things like `java.io.FileInputStream`) then that's where it will find its data.

The exception to this is when you use `ClassLoader::getResource` which will search your classpath to find the specified resource. So, for example, if your classpath points to a single jar file, then the resource will be looked for only in that jar file. Note that if you use a custom ClassLoader implementation then other places can be searched -- URLs, non-classpath paths/jarfiles, etc. Essentially any possible source of bytes could be used by a custom ClassLoader to find resources -- it will depend on what that ClassLoader was designed to do.

Comment: I am using this code: ` ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File (classLoader.getResource(drlFileName).getFile());`

Comment: Is it telling to look inside or outside.

Comment: Ah, I see - class loaders use the classpath, so they end up being the exception to the rule of thumb I mentioned. The resource will be looked up in the class path and may come from the filesystem or a jar depending on where the class loader first finds the specified resource.

Comment: So basically, class loaders can find them in both ways. (inside or outside)?

Comment: Yep - it's all about the classpath at that point. See the update I just made to my answer.